# MySQL 5.6 crashes often after upgrade

Tags: mysql

I noticed in WHM that MySQL 5.5 has an EOL December of 15' and I upgraded to 5.6 and now MySQL crashes at least twice a day, but it restarts after failing.

Here is a sampling of the [error log](http://w3medialabs.com/files-share/sample-log.txt).

Any idea what is going on?

Thank you.

---

8/23/15
Here is another sampling of the error log.

```
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 579981897
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.23 started; log sequence number 579981897
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-08-21 20:58:00 9080 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.23'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
150821 23:25:59 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150821 23:25:59 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2015-08-21 23:25:59 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 581241150
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 581282693
2015-08-21 23:25:59 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.23 started; log sequence number 581282693
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-08-21 23:26:00 13544 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.23'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2015-08-22 02:36:21 13544 [Warning] IP address '223.100.49.242' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
2015-08-22 02:36:56 13544 [Warning] IP address '223.100.49.242' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
2015-08-22 02:37:23 13544 [Warning] IP address '223.100.49.242' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
2015-08-22 11:27:54 13544 [Warning] IP address '122.224.6.150' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
150822 20:54:11 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150822 20:54:11 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2015-08-22 20:54:11 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 506046855 and 506046855 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 589358444 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-08-22 20:54:11 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-08-22 20:54:12 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2015-08-22 20:54:12 15947 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.23 started; log sequence number 589358444
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15947 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.23'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
150822 20:54:13 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150822 20:54:13 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2015-08-22 20:54:13 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 506046855 and 506046855 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 589358444 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2015-08-22 20:54:13 15983 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.23 started; log sequence number 589358444
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-08-22 20:54:14 15983 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.23'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2015-08-22 21:28:15 15983 [Warning] IP address '221.229.162.143' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
150822 23:04:56 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150822 23:04:56 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2015-08-22 23:04:56 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-22 23:04:56 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 590358682
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 590373690
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.23 started; log sequence number 590373690
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-08-22 23:04:57 19131 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.23'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2015-08-23 02:42:47 19131 [Warning] IP address '221.229.162.143' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2015-08-23 10:27:43 19131 [Warning] Hostname 'unassigned.psychz.net' does not resolve to '45.34.1.137'.
2015-08-23 10:27:43 19131 [Note] Hostname 'unassigned.psychz.net' has the following IP addresses:
2015-08-23 10:27:43 19131 [Note]  - 199.15.112.8
2015-08-23 20:42:45 19131 [Warning] IP address '60.191.129.138' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
150823 20:54:08 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150823 20:54:08 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2015-08-23 20:54:08 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 506046855 and 506046855 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 599201345 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2015-08-23 20:54:08 9837 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
150823 20:54:08 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/{hostname}.pid ended
150823 20:57:33 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2015-08-23 20:57:34 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 506046855 and 506046855 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 599201345 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.23 started; log sequence number 599201345
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-08-23 20:57:34 10285 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.23'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL 5.6 is not supposed to use 5.5 unmodified data files - the format changes in every version and, sometimes, it changes even for patch versions.

After an upgrade you should run mysql_upgrade. Then, you can use your database normally.

Comment: I ran the MySQL_upgrade yesterday.  I had to use --force, but it seemed to work.  No crash yet...  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First item of action would be to disconnect from your website immediately to prevent further corruption. One way to do this is to just alter the credentials of your application.

You'll need to perform a repair of the data to fix the inconsistencies in the binary logs.

Please refer to [this article from MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html), which provides steps to repair. The tool mysqlcheck should be available in the command line.

Comment: Files are probably not corrupted at all - they are written in an older format. mysql_check will not change the files format.

Comment: Ah. I was unaware because usually I just did a mysqldump and reimported it after the upgrade (mostly so I don't run into these kinds of problems)

Comment: Yes, in that case you definitely don't need mysql_upgrade. Also, some Linux repositories have packages that automatically run mysql_upgrade after an upgrade. But not all packages do this.